# UIViewController (Modal) Rotation

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I have three modal VCs as follows:

M1 is UIModalPresentationFullScreen

M2 is UIModalPresentationFormSheet

M3 is UIModalPresentationFormSheet

M1 calls M2; M2 calls M3

So, normally, you'll see M1 in the background and M2 as a FormSheet.  If M3 is called it covers M2 until it is closed.

Everything is fine until a rotation occurs while M3 is open.  When rotated to any orientation with M2 & M3 open, M2 goes into a full-screen view (even though it is a form sheet modal), and M3 is properly displayed as a form sheet over M3; but M1 is totally invisible (since it is covered by a full-screen M2).

After rotation, everything works correctly, but M3 should cover M2 and M1 should be in the background.  But what happens is that M2 is full-screen in the background, and M3 is correct.

I have no rotation-related code in M2 or M3.  M1 has the following only:

```
- (void) deviceOrientationDidChange
{
     collectionView.frame = [self collectionViewFrame];
}
```

Which works as it should to change the frame of a collection view (this is a notification based on UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification).

So, I don't know whether this is a bug of mine, or whether this is as-designed behavior by Apple, or what.  It is a little strange I know to have a series of Modals like this, but it does provide the desired effect.

Will appreciate any suggestions from anyone; or recommendations for a workaround if nothing else.

Comment: Did you do any changes like adding frames in view did load of the modalview controller you are presenting?